# Where do the S3 Policy and Secret Key go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, reactjs

I'm new to AWS/S3 and following [this tutorial from Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTExamples.html).

It's not working, and I'm wondering if it's due to the policy section.

- Where does the policy go? For what it's worth, the form is in a React component. I tried putting the one below into the S3 policy in my AWS console, but it didn't like it.
- I see the Access Key goes in the form. Where does the Secret key go? (Rails+React app)

Thanks for any guidance.

Here's the policy:

```
{ "expiration": "2007-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
"conditions": [
{"bucket": "johnsmith"},
["starts-with", "$key", "user/eric/"],
{"acl": "public-read"},
{"success_action_redirect": "http://johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
{"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""]
]
}
```

And the form:

```
<form action="http://johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Key to upload: <input type="input" name="key" value="user/eric/" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html" />
Content-Type: <input type="input" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-uuid" value="14365123651274" />
Tags for File: <input type="input" name="x-amz-meta-tag" value="" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE" />
<input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="POLICY" />
<input type="hidden" name="Signature" value="SIGNATURE" />
File: <input type="file" name="file" /> <br />
<!-- The elements after this will be ignored -->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
</form>
```

...

Comment: Read through that page you linked, again.  The policy is a form post policy document, which is encoded with base64 and included in the form presented to the user and uploaded to S3.  You never include your secret key *anywhere* (it's a **secret**).  You use it to generate the signature that goes in the form.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot. I suppose all that is still a bit over my head. I realized that I need to create a Signature and a Policy, but I'm not sure how to actually do that, and I'm not seeing it in the docs. Might be easy for a vet, but I'ver done this kind of passing of keys around. Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The **Policy** value should be a base64-encoded version of your policy.

The **Signature** should be a hash based on the Policy and the Secret Key.

For example, this Python code (sorry, I don't have equivalent Ruby code handy) will output the two values for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import base64
import hmac, hashlib

policy_document = '{ "expiration": "2007-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
"conditions": [
{"bucket": "johnsmith"},
["starts-with", "$key", "user/eric/"],
{"acl": "public-read"},
{"success_action_redirect": "http://johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
{"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""]
]
}'

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "<SECRET-KEY>"

policy = base64.b64encode(policy_document)

signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, policy, hashlib.sha1).digest())

print policy
print
print signature
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Everything in your form looks alright, except POLICY & SIGNATURE:

   - Policy will be encoded as Base64 which includes some basic info about bucket, expiration, acl, etc,..
   - Signature will be encoded as Base64 as well which includes secret key, and above policy

Here is my example which describes how to generate POLICY & SIGNATURE:

```
    class S3Upload
      attr_reader :policy_document, :signature

      def initialize
        @policy_document = generate_policy_document
        @signature       = generate_signature
      end

      private

      def generate_policy_document
        Base64.encode64(
          {
            expiration: 1.day.from_now.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'),
            conditions: [
              { bucket: YOUR_BUCKET },
              { acl: 'public-read' },
              ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
              { success_action_status: '201' },
              ["starts-with","$content-type", "image/"]
            ]
          }.to_json
        ).gsub(/\n|\r/, '')
      end

      def generate_signature
        Base64.encode64(
          OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
            OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'),
            YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            policy_document
          )
        ).gsub(/\n/, '')
      end
    end
```

You can use this class to export policy & signature, then include to your form.

2. We don't include secret key to form directly, we use it to generate signature as my example above